# how to list the news in home page in concrete5

Tags: concrete5

how to list the news [need to list latest  news ] in home page. I have created the news using the composer in concrete5, its listed successfully in a page of type pagelist, but I am not able to list those in home page.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. There is no "pagelist" page type. Do you mean a block? Why can't you add a Page List block to the home page? Are you getting an error of some kind? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the BlockType "Page List"